# missing $ inserted error for equation

Tags: errors, equations

I get the `missing $ inserted error` for the following code:

```
\begin{equation}

C = $ \frac{2}{\omega^2N^2\mu\pia} $

\end{equation}
```

I have tried out different changes based on Googling for this error, but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Don't put `$` inside the `equation` environment. You can't use math mode (ie, `$...$` inside math mode (ie, `\begin{equation}... \end{equation}`)
2. Don't leave empty lines inside the `equation` environment.
3. `\pia` should be `\pi a`. Note the space.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
   C =  \frac{2}{\omega²N²μ\pi a}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]